# Parameters displayed as arg0 but only the first time?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a happy user of eclipse mars for some time. But there is one thing that bugs me a bit:

When i start eclipse mars in the morning and start typing for example:

```
list.add
```

(list is an arraylist)

Then the parameters are displayed as arg0 and arg1. This only happens the first time. Cause when i type "list.add" again the parameter names are displayed, so no arg0 and arg1 anymore.

But when i go to another class and use it by typing hash.put the parameters are arg0 again. But when i try it a second time the parameters names are correctly displayed, no more arg0 anymore.

I do have a jdk (1.8 60) with source configured and selected (installed jres and for the project).

First try, you'll get arg0:

[image: first with arg0]

Second try the param names:

[image: second with param names]

Solved:

(thanks to francesco foresti for pointing me to the right direction)

Found it! Right click "jre system library", properties, select "execution env" radiobutton, click "environment" button , select "javase-18" and enable the checkbox for jdk in the "compatible jre" list. Now the rt.jar has source attachment instead of only javadoc attachment. And it keeps it even after a maven "update project".

Comment: And you want us to guess based on the code you don't show?

Comment: I don't think he has code to show... I believe he's referring to Eclipse's auto complete / suggestions. Maybe he can post a screenshot to make the meaning clearer

Comment: I think , you should go to following menu , _Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content assist_ and see if option **Fill method arguments and show guessed arguments** is selected to what you are see.

Comment: @dagandlerx i've added a screenshot to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guessing here, so take this answer with a grain of salt..

It is possible that, the first time you ask for an autocomplete Eclipse fills up the parameter names using decompiled classes (coming from your project dependencies), hence you see arg0 arg1 and so on. At the same time Eclipse triggers a source download request (maybe to Maven, I don't know), so the next time you want an autocomplete, you see the parameters' real names. It also seems that this "autocomplete cache" has a limited lifetime, so that when you open Eclipse the next morning, it starts all over again. I'd suggest you try to dig into Eclipse autocomplete configuration if you want to change this behavior.

Comment: This issue has been bugging me as well and I came up with the same explanation for myself. I'm also guessing, however it sounds reasonable.

Comment: Hmm, strange, i do use maven and have a JRE system library in the Package explorer structure, i right click and set the "jre system library" to my jdk one. Now arg0 don't show up the first time. But it seems when i do a "maven > update project" the "jre system library" resets and points again to a jre. And the arg0 show up again. This might be a maven problem. I'll search a bit more.

Comment: Found it! Right click "jre system library", properties, select "execution env" radiobutton, click "environment" button , select "javase-18" and enable the checkbox for jdk in the "compatible jre" list. Now the rt.jar has source attachment instead of only javadoc attachment. And it keeps it even after a maven "update project".